# Can I multiply a register's value by an immediate number to add the result to another register?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

Learning Assembly with NASM, Ubuntu, 32 bits.

My array in `.data`:

```
ary db 1,2,2,4,5 ; Five elements of one byte each
```

And some number:

```
tmp db 2   ; Holds the number 2
```

Let's say I want to print the element at index 4 in the array (so it would be `5`).

I know I could do this:

```
mov EAX,4
mov EBX,0
mov ECX,ary          ; Put the array's address in ECX
add ECX,4            ; Move address four bytes to the right
add byte [ECX],'0'   ; The value at this address to ASCII
mov EDX,1
int 0x80
```

However, for whatever reasons, I decided that instead of writing the constant number `4`, I want to do it by multiplying my variable (which is `2`) by `2`.

This is the updated code:

```
mov EAX,[tmp]   ; Put the number 2 in EAX
mov ECX,ary     ; Put the array's address in ECX
add ECX,EAX * 2 ; Move (2 * 2) = 4 bytes to the right
add byte [ECX],'0' ; Decimal to ASCII
mov EAX,4
mov EBX,0
mov EDX,1
int 0x80
```

This doesn't work at `add ECX,EAX * 2`:

```
invalid operand type
```

But why? Doesn't `ECX` evaluate to `2`? Being equivalent to

```
add ECX,2 * 2
```

Curiously, these do work:

```
add ECX,EAX * 1   ; Moves by 2
add ECX,EAX * 0   ; Moves by 0
```

The above suggests me that the answer is no. And the reason that multiplying by `1` or `0` works is because the assembler doesn't actually need to do any multiplication to know the answer in the first place.

Does this mean that to achieve what I want, I do have to use the `mul` instruction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In x86, although `lea` supports multiplication by a constant, the `add` instruction doesn't support an operand that multiples a register by a constant. It supports additive offsets, but not multiplication. I assume, as you noted, that the assembler is being somewhat forgiving in this case in the accepted syntax of `add ECX,EAX*0` and `add ECX,EAX*1` as being equivalent to `add ECX,0` and `add ECX,EAX`, respectively.

You would instead need do something like this:

```
mov ECX,ary     ; Put the array's address in ECX
mov EAX,[tmp]   ; Put the number 2 in EAX
shl EAX,1       ; (instead of mul EAX,2)
add ECX,EAX     ; Move (2 * 2) = 4 bytes to the right
add byte [ECX],'0' ; Decimal to ASCII
mov EAX,4
mov EBX,0
mov EDX,1
int 0x80
```

Comment: @johnfound sorry I missed the case of `lea`. I modified the answer to not be as inclusive about the supporting instructions. But to be clear, it doesn't universally support the mechanism.

Comment: Your answer is not generally wrong. Only in the context of the question. :)

Answer (score 4):

You CAN do multiplication and adding in one instruction if you use `lea`:

```
lea ECX,[ECX+EAX*2]
```

Answer (score 1):

The instruction `LEA` can be used to provide two additions and one limited multiplication at once. The common syntax is:

```
lea reg, [offset+reg+const*reg]
```

Here, `reg` is any register, `offset` is some constant number and `const` is one of 1, 2, 4 or 8 constant.

This way, this instruction is very powerful is order to compute some pretty complex equations:

The equation from the question:

```
add ECX,EAX * 2
```

can be computed this way:

```
lea ecx, [ecx+2*eax]
```

There are many other uses:

```
lea  eax, [ebx+2*ebx] ; eax = 3*ebx
lea  eax, [eax+4*eax] ; eax = 5*eax
lea  eax, [ecx+8*ecx] ; eax = 9*ecx
lea  eax, [1234+ebx+8*ecx]
```

Note, that FASM allows shorter syntax for the above examples:

```
lea  eax, [3*ebx]
lea  eax, [5*eax]
lea  eax, [9*ecx]
```

Additional advantage of `lea` instruction is that it does not affects the flags. The execution speed of this instruction is very fast on all x86 CPU.